# How To Set Max Width And Max Height Of Image Before Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was wondering how can i set max width and max height before the image is uploaded. So when you click on choose file, you select your picture and it loads up so you can see it. Then you crop it then eventually select upload to save it in a directory now my question is how can i set max width and max height before you get a chance to preview it after you select it in when prompt after selecting choose file.

Once You Choose Your File If The Image Is Higher Than The Max Height And Max Width Throw a Message and ask them for a smaller picture

HTML CODE:

```
<img id="uploadPreview" style="display:none;"/>

<!-- image uploading form -->
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" accept="image/jpeg" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">

<!-- hidden inputs -->
<input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
<input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
<input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
<input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
</form>
```

Jquery CODE:

```
function setInfo(i, e) {
    $('#x').val(e.x1);
    $('#y').val(e.y1);
    $('#w').val(e.width);
    $('#h').val(e.height);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var p = $("#uploadPreview");

    // prepare instant preview
    $("#uploadImage").change(function(){
        // fadeOut or hide preview
        p.fadeOut();

        // prepare HTML5 FileReader
        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
        };
    });

    // implement imgAreaSelect plug in (http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/)
    $('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        onSelectEnd: setInfo
    });
});
```

Comment: additional suggestion you can use [Jquery FileUpload plugin](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/). It's so easy to use and applicable in your case

Comment: @DrixsonOseña check it out http://demo.w3bees.com/jquery-image-crop/

Comment: @DrixsonOseña choose A Photo And Once You do You Can View It Then Crop It Now Before the photo is viewable i wanted to know how can i check the width and height and check if its higher than the max width and height

Answer (score 0):

this is the part you need to edit

aspectRatio: '1:1',

try like this aspectRatio: '1:1.3',

you will see the ratio of the croping area will change

Answer (score -1):

Are you using Jcrop to crop the image ?
If yes then they have provided the parameter to limit the maxWidth and maxHeight..

If you are using custom div overlapping the previewed image asa acropped region then set maxwidth and maxheight to that div.

eg.

```
setSelect: [ 50, 50, 274, 196 ],
                maxSize: [224, 146],
                minSize: [224, 146],
```

Comment: @ThinkkSo, see the documents. I guess you need to do in PHP and it's very easy

Comment: $('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
        // set crop ratio (optional)
        aspectRatio: '1:1',
        maxSize: [224, 146],
        minSize: [224, 146],
        onSelectEnd: setInfo,
    });

Comment: yes, exactly..but please confitm that this parameters are accepted by prototype you are using..

My code would restrict the user from selecting assigned region at max..

Comment: hey, find the documentation @ http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html

$('img#uploadPreview').imgAreaSelect({
  // set crop ratio (optional)
  aspectRatio: '1:1',
  onSelectEnd: setInfo,
        maxHeight: 100,
        maxWidth: 100
 });

This code worked for me..

Comment: heyy,

oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = oFREvent.target.result;

            image.onload = function() {
                console.log(this.width);
                console.log(this.height);
                // access image size here & do further implementation
            };

      p.attr('src', oFREvent.target.result).fadeIn();
  };

This code might help you..